# What is the best tool for creating simple iOS demo videos

Tags: video-editor, mac, ios, tutorial

I need to create some simple video tutorials for an iOS app. The tutorials will consist largely of screen footage showing the app being used with voice over and some titles. I know how to capture the video from the iPhone (Apple has made that easy). I'm looking for the best simple tool for editing the video, putting in some titles, and adding the voice over.

The original iMove would have been great for this. Unfortunately that product no longer exists; it was replaced with something designed to package vacation & birthday party video with theme overlays and all sorts of automatic stuff I don't want and can't use.

I will be working on a MacBook Air with 8GB of RAM. I could buy Final Cut Pro and would probably be comfortable with the model it presents, but I recognize it is way way overkill for what I need to do.

Comment: Possibly http://alternativeto.net/software/avidemux/

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't used iMovie in a few years, I recommend you give it a try. It does exactly what you're looking for. If you create a new movie rather than a trailer, it will just create a timeline that you can drop footage into. On the left, under your events and library is a section called "Titles" that has dozens of titles ranging from tasteful to playful. You use the "V" key to record a voiceover.

FCPX is also a great easy tool to learn. In fact, iMovie is now made so that you can transition easily from using iMovie into using Final Cut Pro X. I think they might even share some of their internal bits. In any event, if you use one, you can probably do some stuff easily in the other.

Comment: Thanks, I've done this and you're right. There are a few awkward things, but generally it's working very well.